# dataproc rename files written by spark in GCS folder

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using Dataproc to implement spark jobs using Scala. The aim of my spark job is to read data in GCS make some transformations and then write result data under GCS. The files we got from spark write are PART-00 , I want to rename them, but I can't find any solution as the written files are under gcs and not hdfs. Any idea how to solve this please. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

On a Dataproc cluster, you can still run the same `hadoop fs -mv` commands against GCS the same way you would for HDFS, except you use the full "gs://bucket/filename..." path.

Comment: Additionally, in Spark (or PySpark) you can use the [gs:// prefix](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage#using_the_connector).